# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error with strcpy() (suspected)

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcpy

I am having trouble trying to this runtime segmentation fault in this short piece of code. I suspect it has something to do with the use of system() and strcpy() in the code but as I am not experienced with this type of error, I am unsure what to do and I have not found many helpful pages so far.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
        char command[31], string[128];
        strcpy(string, (char *)system("grep -Po '(?<=testString\\s)\\S+' File"));
        string[strlen(string)] = '\0';
        printf("%s", string);
        return 0;
}
```

I am using GCC 4.7.3 to compile the program. I would really appreciate any help with this a lot.

Comment: You're casting the `int` return value of [`system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) to a string... No good can come of that.

Comment: Your usage of `system` is wrong, you may want to use [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html)

Comment: When using a system or other API cal, you should read the documentation regarding that call to determine what it accepts and returns. `system` does not return the output of the command you are executing. It only provides a return code. If you want to capture output, you can either have the `system` call output to a file that you open and read after the call, or use pipes (`popen`, etc).

Comment: Besides the `system` error, the line `string[strlen(string)] = '\0';` is completely stupid! If string doesn't contain a 0 at the end, `strlen` will search for one even past past the buffer and then you will write a 0 on an already existing 0. The statement does quite wastefully, at best nothing, at worst a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @tristopia, I'll remove that line.

Comment: @jkrix: Just change it to `string[127] = '\0';`. Better yet, create an integer constant called `MAX_LEN` and set it equal to `127`. Might as well rename `string` to something more meaningful, like `cmdOutput`

Comment: I didn't bother with any of that as this piece of code was just a small test for another piece of software, even though it is a good habit. Thanks for the help to everyone who contributed here, my main code works fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `system` command returns -1 on error or the return status of the command otherwise.

Type casting this `integer return value` is causing the `segmentation fault` in this case.

To copy the output of the command into a buffer we could use `popen` which returns a file pointer `FILE *` from which you can read the command output.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{

  FILE *fp;
  char string[128];


  /* Open the command for reading. */
  fp = popen("grep -Po '(?<=testString\\s)\\S+' File ", "r");

  if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        exit;
  }

  /* Read the output of command */
  while (fgets(string, sizeof(string)-1, fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", string);
  }

  /* Close */
  pclose(fp);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`system` does not return `char *` but `int`. Using its return value as string - `char *` - most likely will give you segfault.

> int system(const char *command);
>
> RETURN VALUE
>          The value returned is -1 on  error  (e.g.   fork(2)  failed),  and  the
>          return  status  of the command otherwise.  This latter return status is
>          in the format specified in wait(2).  Thus, the exit code of the command
>          will  be  WEXITSTATUS(status).   In case /bin/sh could not be executed,
>          the exit status will be that of a command that does exit(127).

Comment: Thanks for the very quick responses! Thanks @mbratch, I'll definitely look into that :)